# The @github.com is attached to my e-mail when commiting. Why?

Tags: github

```
$ git push
Username for 'https://github.com': myemail@gmail.com
Password for 'https://myemail@gmail.com@github.com': xxxxx
```

I don't understand why it is `@gmail.com@github.com` instead of just `@gmail.com` when asked for the password. I checked my .gitconfig which is configured correctly I would say:

```
[user]
    name  = Zoltan King
    email = myemail@gmail.com
```

Any idea how can I get rid of that `@github.com` thing when the password is asked.

The remote address looks like so:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/username/myrepo.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/username/myrepo.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

Comment: What the remote's address (`git remote show origin`)? How did you clone the repo.?

Comment: I have just created a new repo but I get the same when using `git clone address` and update something in an existing repo.

Comment: I updated my post with the output of `git remote show origin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username on GitHub is not your email address. So when asked for the username as below, you can't enter the email address:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': zoltan-king
```

Comment: you're right but if I don't type the email, just the username as you suggested,  I get something like this at the password prompt: `Password for 'https://username@github.com'` I don't have an e-mail like that ending in `@github.com`. Mine ends in @gmail.com

Comment: I checked my e-mail settings on the GitHub profile page and I have the gmail address set there. I don't remember setting `@github.com` anywhere.

Comment: That's normal. In `https://username@github.com`, `github.com` is the website to which you're connecting and `username` is simply your login. It's not expecting a `username@github.com` email address. Just type your username, then your password and it should work :-)